# Grid not displaying its rows

Tags: winforms, grid, infragistics

I'm using `Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid` version `Infragistics4.Win.UltraWinGrid.v13.1`
and I have some problem getting this code running properly.

```
// creating the dataSource object which is a wrapper for a System.Data.DataTable
dataSource.FillTheValues();
Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid grid = new Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGrid();

grid.DataSource = dataSource.Table; //dataSource.Table is a System.Data.DataTable
grid.DataBind();
grid.PerformLayout();
```

At this point something very strange happens (checked in debug mode):

- `dataSource.Table.Rows.Count` is 1203
- `grid.Rows.Count` is 1203

but in the actual grid in my form nothing is displayed and the grid appears totally empty.

The Columns in the grid perfectly macth the one in the `dataSource.Table`, so the binding is fine.

Additionally, I've tried to invoke `grid.Update`, `grid.Refresh`, `grid.Invalidate` but no result.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: In WinForms you don't need DataBind and PerformLayout

Comment: And, by the way, did you add the manually created grid instance to the forms controls collection?

Comment: @Lorenzo there isn't enough information to determine what may be the cause.  Steve makes a good point to ensure that the grid is added to the form and you should verify that it is the instance that you see.

Comment: The Grid is added to the forms control at design type, by dragging it into the components from the toolbox window frame.
I've cross-checked and the grid correctly appears in the automatically Designer generated C# code.
@Steve: thanks for the info concerning DataBind and PerformLayout, I've removed them from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code above, you declare and initialize **a new instance** of the UltraGrid and then you fill this new instance with the datasource. This grid instance is not the same grid that you have created and put on the form surface with the designer. It is just an object filled with data but never displayed.

You could resolve this problem using the variable reference to the grid designed with the form Designer (If you haven't changed the name property in the designer, it should be named `ultraGrid1`)

```
 dataSource.FillTheValues();
 ultraGrid1.DataSource = dataSource.Table;
```